# What using statements are needed to use Deedle in C#? "Could not load type 'Deedle.Frame'" exception

Tags: c#, exception, deedle

2nd Edit: I have found a MS log viewer, which does not enlighten me. Here is what it shows:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (10/15/2020 @ 4:09:38 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\IntelliTrace.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/IntelliTrace/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = IntelliTrace.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\IntelliTrace.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/IntelliTrace/Microsoft.Web.Administration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/IntelliTrace/Microsoft.Web.Administration/Microsoft.Web.Administration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/IntelliTrace/deps/Microsoft.Web.Administration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/IntelliTrace/deps/Microsoft.Web.Administration/Microsoft.Web.Administration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/IntelliTrace/Microsoft.Web.Administration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/IntelliTrace/Microsoft.Web.Administration/Microsoft.Web.Administration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/IntelliTrace/deps/Microsoft.Web.Administration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/IntelliTrace/deps/Microsoft.Web.Administration/Microsoft.Web.Administration.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Edit: I have changed the namespace, but the error message has not changed.

I have a very short C# program. I am trying to use Deedle for the first time. Unfortunately, all of the examples I've found online only show executable code and not whatever using statements are needed at the top. None of the pages I found when I search addressed this. Here is the error message.

> System.TypeLoadException
> HResult=0x80131522
> Message=Could not load type 'Deedle.Frame' from assembly 'Deedle, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
> Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
> StackTrace:
> <Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Deedle;

namespace DeedleCaller
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var msftRaw = Frame.ReadCsv(@"C:\Users\afargnoli\Documents\ASRD\Devel\SRFN Data Analytics\link_success_rates\kennett_intervals_jan.csv");
            msftRaw.Print();
            Console.WriteLine("\nPause");
            string unused = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should start with not using Deedle as your own namespace but come up with something unique. Also, have you installed the Deedle-nuget package?

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to do that and failed. Visual Studio tells me I can't rename elements that are defined in metadata.

Comment: You can change _your_ namespace just by changing it in code (so, change `namespace Deedle` to `namespace MyDeedleApp` or something similar).

Comment: Thanks. I've changed the namespace, but the exception has not changed. I've updated the question.

Comment: How is Deedle installed? What version of .NET Framework or Core are you using? What IDE are you using?

Comment: NuGet package manager, .NET Framework 4.6.1, and Visual Studio. I began with a Project, Namespace, and Assembly all named Deedle, which misled the binder. I've changed all that and it runs now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...Message=Could not load type 'Deedle.Frame' from assembly 'Deedle...
```

This tells you, you don't have the assemblies which might be present in the Nuget of Deedle: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Deedle

Also, as Thomas said, it would be better if you changed your namespace. i.e."DoodleProject".

Do this last thing by making a new project with the new namespace, then download the nugget and it should be working.

Comment: Thanks! I did it the hard way. Instead of starting with a new project, I went in and changed all the places where VS put my original project name ("Deedle"). After I changed the Assembly's name, it worked!